# Drag & Drap doesn't work with custom Window.Style

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple UI made with wpf. In there is a Page containig a CustomControl with a TreeView. To reorder the TreeNodes i am using wpf dragdrop. This works pretty well so far. Now i'm playing around with WindowChrome to create a borderless window. But the Problem: Now Drag & Drop won't work. If i try to drag an object the curser changes into a "no valid drop position"

What i've found out: If i delete my custom  evererything works. But i have now idea what is missing to get the drag and drop function working with my custom style.

The TreeView:

```
    <TreeView x:Name="StructureTree"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  Padding="10,20,20,0"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RootElement.Children}"
                  Background="{x:Null}" 
                  BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                  dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="true"
                  dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="true"
                  dd:DragDrop.UseDefaultDragAdorner="true">
```

The Window.Resources:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}">
     <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">

                        <!-- Outer border with the dropshadow margin -->
                        <Border Padding="{Binding OuterMargin, FallbackValue=10}">

                            <!-- Main window outline -->
                            <Grid>

                                <!-- Opacity mask for corners on grid -->
                                <Border x:Name="Container"
                                        Background="{StaticResource BackgroundVeryLightBrush}"
                                        CornerRadius="{Binding WindowCornerRadius}" />

                                <!-- Window border and dropshadown -->
                                <Border CornerRadius="{Binding WindowCornerRadius}"
                                    Background="{Binding BackgroundVeryLightBrush}" BorderBrush="#FF1E1E1E">
                                    <Border.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2" Opacity="0.2" BlurRadius="5" />
                                    </Border.Effect>
                                    <Border.OpacityMask>
                                        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Container}" />
                                    </Border.OpacityMask>
                                </Border>

                                <!-- The main window content -->
                                <Grid>

                                    <!-- Corner clipping -->
                                    <Grid.OpacityMask>
                                        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Container}" />
                                    </Grid.OpacityMask>

                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        <!-- Title Bar -->
                                        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding TitleHeight, FallbackValue=42}"/>
                                        <!-- Window Content -->
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>

                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <!-- Title Bar -->
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Panel.ZIndex="1">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <!-- Icon -->
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <!-- Title -->
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <!-- Window Buttons -->
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>

                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <!-- Icon -->
                                        <Button Margin="1" Padding="0" Style="{StaticResource IconButton}" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" Command="{Binding MenuCommand}">
                                            <!--<Image Source="/Images/Logo/Icon.ico"/>-->
                                        </Button>

                                        <!-- Title -->
                                        <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0">
                                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleText}"                                              
                                                       Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Title, FallbackValue= 'Wellcome'}"/>
                                        </Viewbox>

                                        <!-- Window Buttons -->
                                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Button Command="{Binding MinimizeCommand}" Style="{StaticResource WindowControlButton}" Content="_"/>
                                            <Button Command="{Binding MaximizeCommand}" Style="{StaticResource WindowControlButton}" Content="[ ]"/>
                                            <Button Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" Style="{StaticResource WindowCloseButton}" Content="X"/>
                                        </StackPanel>

                                    </Grid>
                                    <!-- Page Content -->
                                    <Border Grid.Row="1" Padding="{Binding InnerContentPadding}">
                                        <ContentPresenter   Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was experimenting with a similar scenario I found that WPF won't allow to drop an item if it can't detect a control under the cursor. The solution to this may be to add a stretched rectangle "under" your TreeView with transparent filling:

```
    <Rectangle
        Fill="Transparent"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <TreeView x:Name="StructureTree"...
```

Just so a control could be "under" your cursor and then you should get back your valid drop area.

**Edit:**

If it doesn't want to work, try to put the rectangle before this part in the template:

```
<!-- Opacity mask for corners on grid -->
<Border x:Name="Container"
        Background="{StaticResource BackgroundVeryLightBrush}"
        CornerRadius="{Binding WindowCornerRadius}" />
```

And since the basic window template uses AdornerDecorator, it's worth a shot to include in your template too, where needed:

```
<AdornerDecorator>
    <ContentPresenter.../>
</AdornerDecorator>
```

Comment: I've added the rectangle but the problem still exist

Comment: I think i am missing something int the <ControlTemplate> if i delete the ControlTemplate darg and drop works

Comment: So, yeah, I have other methods to style my windows, and that's should be the difference here. Edited answer with more ideas.